# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (angular-cli build) on project

Tags: angular, maven, angular-cli

I have a problem building an Angular web application with maven. It seems the maven plugin doesn't recognize angular-cli. I tried to uninstall and install angular cli. The maven plugin used

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>angular-cli build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>ng</executable>
                            <arguments>                             
                                <argument>build</argument>
                                <argument>app-ng</argument>
                                <argument>--configuration</argument>
                                <argument>${angular.build.prod}</argument>                              
                                <argument>--base-href</argument>
                                <argument>"/${angular.module.name}/"</argument>
                            </arguments>
                            <workingDirectory>src/main/angular/${angular.module.name}</workingDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

The error received is

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (angular-cli build) @ web ---
Workspace extension with invalid name (defaultProject) found.
You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (angular-cli build) on project web: Command execution failed.: Process exited with an error: 2 (Exit value: 2) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (angular-cli build) on project web: Command execution failed.
```

The versions:

```
Angular CLI: 16.1.5
Node: 18.16.0
Package Manager: npm 9.5.1
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1601.2
@angular-devkit/core         16.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   16.1.5 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          16.1.5 (cli-only)
```